# Add property content description in back button android navigation bar

Tags: android

I'm implementing talkback descriptions in my app, and I want to know if is posible add content description in this button.

[image]

I'm searching information, but I don't know how to looking for exactly.

Answer (score 0):

TalkBack should already say "Back Button" whenever you focus on the button you highlighted above.

As for changing the `contentDescription` to whatever you want, I don't think this is possible especially since not all devices have this button anymore -- See some of the new Pixel devices as an example.

Comment: Yes I know, that buttons says "Atrás" in Spanish. But I want to customize the message, is a requeriment. Thanks for the answer, surely is not posible.

Comment: I'm sure the button says the word "Back" on whatever language your device is defaulted on. Maybe try changing back to English if you don't want the localization services to kick in?

Comment: Jajaja, yes, "Atrás" is correct, but the requeriment is "Regresar a la pantalla anterior", equals to back button on the navbar. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh so, the localization is on purpose. Well, in that case, your best bet might be to 1. Add a back button to your `ActionBar` and only have that read what you want or 2. Override what happens when you click on the back button and attempt to read whatever you want out loud. Additionally, why not take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service)